# Apache Struts: Cannot retrieve ActionForward

Tags: apache, jsp, struts

I am trying to learn the Apache Struts framework and I have written a small application that does class enrollments but whenever I try and load up my application it just spits out the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: 
  org.apache.jasper.JasperException: 
    javax.servlet.ServletException: 
      javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot create rewrite URL: 
          java.net.MalformedURLException: Cannot retrieve ActionForward named adminLogin
```

My `index.jsp` page looks like:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic"%>
<logic:redirect forward="showLogin"/>
```

The relevant parts of my `struts-config.xml`:

```
<global-forwards>
    <forward name="showLogin" path="/showLogin.do" />
</global-forwards>
<action-mappings>
    <action path="/showLogin" forward="/pages/choose.jsp" />
    <action path="/adminLogin" forward="/pages/adminLogin.jsp" />
</action-mappings>
```

And finally the `choose.jsp` file:

```
<%@ page import="javax.sql.*"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>

<h1>Who are you?</h1>
<ul>
    <li><html:link forward="adminLogin">Administrator</html:link></li>
    <li><html:link forward="instructorLogin">Instructor</html:link></li>
    <li><html:link forward="studentLogin">Student</html:link></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you're learning Struts for Work, then, well, OK. If you're learning it for "fun", then stop, turn around, and run to something else. Either Struts 2 or Stripes at least. Struts 1 was novel back in 1999, but offers pretty much no value today. JSP 2.0 with JSTL and EL and a modern framework like Stripes or Struts 2 are much more worthy of your time. Better off learning raw Servlets than Struts 1.

Comment: It's for school actually and I don't have a choice in the matter. If I had a choice I would have ditched it already. It's very frustrating and abstract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't do Struts, so don't pin me on it, but the error seems to indicate that it is expecting a `<forward name="adminLogin" />` somewhere in the config. You might want to have the same for the other two forwards.